# Why isn't the mouse working with DragonflyBSD in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, dragonflybsd

I have been facing the problem for months, where I can't run startx and startxfce4 after installing those packages

As mentioned [here](https://www.dragonflybsd.org/docs/how_to_get_to_the_desktop/) I have to run `Xorg -configure` to start off. But when I run the same, the last 2 lines I get are:

> Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file
>
> Abort trap (core dumped)

Now if I ignore `Xorg -configure`, and simply run `startx`, it says

> xauth:  file /root/.serverauth.766 does not exist
>
> xauth:  (stdin):1:  bad display name ":0" in "add" command
>
> xauth:   (argv):1:   bad display name ":0" in "list" command
>
> xauth:   (stdin):1: bad display name ":0" in "add" command

And after a while:

> xauth: (argv):1:    bad display name "/unix:0" in "list" command

The contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log looks like this:
[image]

If I press ^C, `startx` runs successfully, I see 3 terminals, as expected, but the mouse doesn't work at all. I can't move the mouse and click anything. The keyboard works on the activated terminal.

If I do startxfce4, xfce4 starts, but again, mouse doesn't work.

I have tried changing the `Pointing Device` in VirtualBox, but none from the available options worked.

I also had a previous installation which worked fine until I deleted the VM. After that whenever I try to reinstall DragonflyBSD, I get errors like these.

Is there a way to fix this whole issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your /etc/rc.conf make sure you include `moused_enable="YES"` at the end or else the mouse will not work. I just had this issue as well that that solved it for me.

Comment: That didn't work for me. In fact my previous DragonflyBSD installation was buggy (xorg won't start), too. I just installed FreeBSD later on.